# How to get VBA to look at cell value and not the function in the cell

Tags: function, vba, variables, excel

Ok, so I need to set the value of a variable to the function-result in a cell. So, my cells look something like this:

7         100

7         238

9         152

however the 7 and 9 are a value that I looked up from another sheet in the workbook. But I need to reference the 7 or the 9 in my VBA code.

```
winsize = Range("C" & a).Value 'determine window size
```

I need winsize to be an integer, so the data type and the cell type are different. How do I call the cell value and not the function?

Comment: `Range("C" & a).Value` will give you the value of that cell.

Comment: But I'm getting the mismatch error because winsize is an integer.

Comment: try `Val(Range("C" & a).Value)`

Comment: or `Val(Trim(Range("C" & a).Value))`

Comment: I do not understand what is the value of `a`, and what you have in `"C"&a`. Can you post the output of `typename(Range("C" & a).Value)`? Perhaps `winsize = CInt(Range("C" & a).Value)` works.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, as soon as I asked it, I went back to my code and fixed it. I added another variable. I changed from above to:

```
window = Range("C" & a).Value 'Identify window
winsize = window
```

Where window is a long and winsize is an integer. And now it all works fine. Off to the next issue...